# Failed to finalize session : INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_APK: /data/app/....tmp/...-debug version code 29 inconsistent with 28

Tags: android, android-studio, android-testing, android-studio-3.0, android-build

This error happens when i try to  run the app on the simulator:

[image]

It asks if it can uninstall the current application but there is no application installed on the simulator. If i click ok, just fails.

I try to invalidate cache and restart, to reboot the pc, to create a new simulator, to update Android studio, all failed with this error.

My current android studio version is 3.2.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved by changing app version from 29 to 30.
Doesn't make much sense but the error is gone.

Maybe, somehow, has to do with a previous build of a signed APK, version 29. It start to happen just after.

Answer (score 2):

Disable Instant Run then invalidate cache and restart

```
 File --> Settings --> Build, Execution, Deployment --> Instant Run-->Uncheck Enable Instant Run
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the user account in emulator, I encounter the same problem with real device. so I changed the user account between user and guest and delete the installed application. then I could install the new version